# TypeScript validation doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript validation.

From my own hook I get an array (posts) that has the type of `Post[] | undefined`.

I then use `Array.prototype.map` on that array. TypeScript should give an error like `"'posts' is probably 'undefined'"` and make me change my code from `posts.map` to `posts?.map`. Unfortunately, I have no errors.

I took a screenshot to explain what I mean:
[image]

usePosts implementation:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

interface Post {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    userId: number;
  }

  const usePosts = () => {
    const fetchPosts = () =>
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((res) => res.data);

    return useQuery<Post[], Error>({
        queryKey: ["posts"],
        queryFn: fetchPosts,
        staleTime: 10 * 1000
    });
  }

  export default usePosts;
```

I use Visual Studio Code, do you know why I get no errors?

Comment: What's the implementation of `usePosts`?

Comment: 1. Do you have `strictNullChecks` enabled in your tsconfig? 2. Why would you use `undefined` instead of an empty array as the default value? I admit that doesn't *answer* the question, but it *does* sidestep the problem you're having. 3 [Don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.).

Comment: @AluanHaddad I added the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we check out the [the documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/typescript#type-narrowing) for how to work with `useQuery` in TypeScript, we come across the amswer.

`useQuery` returns a union type such that if we check the response for success the language knows that `data` is necessary defined.

Thus when you write

```
if (response.error) return;
```

TypeScript determins that any code after the conditional return has a defined `data` property.